# Styling <select> element and its options

Tags: html, css

I've had a good serach and found some options, managed to style the  element itself.

However failed to style the options, I have several dropdowns and need to style them all the same, but all of the solutions that I find don't seem to be working or have HTML missing, or use input area for the new dropdown and I just can't have the cursor visible

```
<select>
  <option>Test1</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My guess is that your “blinking text entering dash” is called [the cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(computers)) (or caret).

Answer (score 3):

These two links might give you a headstart for styling with CSS:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single-option/

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/

Answer (score 0):

Try styling the tag < option> like this in a stylesheet.

```
option { /* styles go here*/ }
```